# Serial Port Receive Thread Not Behaving as Expected - C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2008, serial-communication

My application uses a separate thread for handling received serial data asynchronously.  The PC gets into the receive-handler as expected, but from there things go weird.

This is my thread function:

```
// Create event for OVERLAPPED structure.
s_ov.hEvent = ::CreateEvent(
    NULL,                           // No security
    TRUE,                           // Create a manual-reset event object
    FALSE,                          // Initial state is non-signaled
    NULL                            // No name specified
    );

// Load event handles.
pHandles[0] = s_hSerialPortRxThreadExitEvent;

while ( bContinue )
{
    if ( !::WaitCommEvent( s_hSerialPort, &dwEventMask, &s_ov ) )
    {
        if ( ::GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING )
        {
            TRACE(_T("SerialPortRxThreadFn : Call to WaitCommEvent failed.\r\n\tError: %d\r\n\tFile: %s\r\n\tLine: %d\r\n"), ::GetLastError(), __WFILE__, __LINE__);
            return ::GetLastError();
        }
    }

    pHandles[1] = s_ov.hEvent;

    dwObjectWaitState = ::WaitForMultipleObjects( 2, pHandles, FALSE, INFINITE );

    switch ( dwObjectWaitState )
    {
    case WAIT_ABANDONED:
        TRACE(_T("SerialPortRxThreadFn : Owner thread terminated prematurely.\r\n\tError: %d\r\n\tFile: %s\r\n\tLine: %d\r\n"), ERROR_ARENA_TRASHED, __WFILE__, __LINE__);
        return ERROR_ARENA_TRASHED;
        break;

    case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
        TRACE(_T("SerialPortRxThreadFn : The timeout is set to INFINITE; there should be no timeout.  State is nonsignaled.\r\n\tError: %d\r\n\tFile: %s\r\n\tLine: %d\r\n"), WAIT_TIMEOUT, __WFILE__, __LINE__);
        return WAIT_TIMEOUT;
        break;

    case WAIT_FAILED:
        TRACE(_T("SerialPortRxThreadFn : Call to WaitCommEvent failed.\r\n\tError: %d\r\n\tFile: %s\r\n\tLine: %d\r\n"), ::GetLastError(), __WFILE__, __LINE__);
        return ::GetLastError();
        break;

    case WAIT_OBJECT_0:             // thread exit event signalled
        bContinue = FALSE;

        if ( !::ResetEvent( pHandles[0] ) )
        {
            TRACE(_T("SerialPortRxThreadFn  : Failed to reset the serial port thread exit event.\r\n\tError: %d\r\n\tFile: %s\r\n\tLine: %d\r\n"), ::GetLastError(), __WFILE__, __LINE__);
            return ::GetLastError();
        }
        break;

    case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:         // OVERLAPPED structure event signalled
        // Read data from serial port.
        if ( !::ReadFile( s_hSerialPort, pBuf, RX_BUF_SIZE, &dwWritten, &s_ov ) ) // <- Set breakpoint here
        {
            TRACE(_T("SerialPortRxThreadFn : Call to ReadFile filed.\r\n\tError: %d\r\n\tFile: %s\r\n\tLine: %d\r\n"), ::GetLastError(), __WFILE__, __LINE__);
            return ::GetLastError();
        }

        // Discontinue thread operation if there are no more bytes in the serial port receive buffer.
        if ( dwWritten == 0 ) // <- Or, set breakpoint here
        {
            bContinue = FALSE;
        }
        // Copy the received bytes to the thread-safe buffer.
        else if ( !s_pobjRxRingBuffer->Add( pBuf, dwWritten, TRUE ) )
        {
            TRACE(_T("SerialPortRxThreadFn : Failed to add bytes to ring buffer.\r\n\tError: %d\r\n\tFile: %s\r\n\tLine: %d\r\n"), ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER, __WFILE__, __LINE__);
            return ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER;
        }
        else if ( s_SpCallbackFn != NULL )
        {
            // Notify application of received data.
            if ( (dwRetVal = s_SpCallbackFn( s_pobjRxRingBuffer->ItemsInBuffer() )) != ERROR_SUCCESS )
            {
                TRACE(_T("SerialPortRxThreadFn : Serial port callback function failed.\r\n\tError: %d\r\n\tFile: %s\r\n\tLine: %d\r\n"), dwRetVal, __WFILE__, __LINE__);
                return dwRetVal;
            }
        }

        if ( !::ResetEvent( pHandles[1] ) )
        {
            TRACE(_T("SerialPortRxThreadFn : Failed to reset the OVERLAPPED structure event.\r\n\tError: %d\r\n\tFile: %s\r\n\tLine: %d\r\n"), ::GetLastError(), __WFILE__, __LINE__);
            return ::GetLastError();
        }
        break;

    default:
        // Do nothing.
        break;
    }
}

::CloseHandle( s_ov.hEvent );

return ERROR_SUCCESS;
```

If I set my breakpoint on the line calling `ReadFile` everything works as I expect, and the PC gets into the callback function.  However, if I set my breakpoint at the next line, where `dwWritten` is evaluated for zero, it is zero, the expression evaluates as TRUE, and the loop exits; the PC never gets to the callback.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you're doing a lot more work than you need to. Why are you handling serial data asynchronously on a thread? Why not just let the thread block on I/O?

Comment: Also you are leaking the Handle, you may not return from the function without closing the handle but you are doing so on error conditions.

Comment: You have to reset the event pHandles[1] before call to ReadFile.

Comment: @Luis: Not true, from the documentation: "ReadFile resets the event to a nonsignaled state when it begins the I/O operation."

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no expert on the Win32 API, but it sure sounds like a timing issue (which is a common cause of [heisenbugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unusual_software_bug#Heisenbug).) Let's say by the time you get to `ReadFile`, there is no data to read. Breaking into the debugger might give it enough of a pause for the data to arrive, so when you resume/step over `ReadFile`, it succeeds.

There are lots of things other than the arrival of data that could trigger the event. You may want to check your [`dwEventMask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363479%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see if my hypothesis is true.

Comment: Everything you said is true, but the suggestion is bad.  Using `dwEventMask` is the wrong way to find out if data has been received.  The right way is to call `SetCommTimeouts` and the `ReadFile` so the read completes as soon as data is in the kernel receive buffer.  `WaitCommEvent` tells you other things, like the state of the flow control pins.

Comment: @Ben Perhaps I wasn't clear. I didn't mean that the handling should be based on `dwEventMask`. I meant that `dwEventMask` should be examined to establish whether my hypothesis is true.

Comment: Prior to starting the thread, `EV_RXCHAR` is the only flag I set in my call to `SetCommMask`.  Are there still other flags that `WaitCommEvent` could retrieve?  I thought that it would only retrieve flags that are set in the mask.

Comment: @Jim TBH, I am not an expert on this API. I'll leave it to someone more knowledgeable than I am to answer your question.

Comment: I seem to have resolved to problem by adding critical section locks and changing the if-else ladder into a series of if statements.  You're suggestion about heisenbugs is probably closest to what I was experiencing, so I'm accepting your answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty painful to watch this code, written some of it.  The verbosity of it is, well, best stuck in somebody else's class library.  A couple of Red Flags.  You assume that the WaitCommEvent() completion means that you can call ReadFile().  Not typically, the event mask you used isn't visible, but there are lots of other reasons that the serial port wants to tell you something.  Another problem is that WaitCommEvent might complete right away.  It not uncommonly does, something available in the receive buffer.

Steal this code from somewhere, it's hard code.  It's been done.

Comment: Prior to starting the thread, `EV_RXCHAR` is the only flag I set in my call to `SetCommMask`.  Unfortunately, borrowing code from outside the company is not an option in this case.  I can look at examples, ect., but all the code has to be written by myself or someone else in the company.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of WaiCommEvent states that after you Used a wait function (like WaitForMultipleEObjects(...)) ,you use the GetOverlappedResult(...) function to get the results of your operation. There should be no need for Read\Write-File(...).

Comment: You can't get the received bytes without calling `ReadFile`.  In fact it is `ReadFile` that is needed and `WaitCommEvent` is not.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I think you're wrong. If you read the documetation on WaitCommEvent ,you can read that there's a flag called EV_RXCHAR for the EventMask-parameter. And ReadFile is choice not a need.

Comment: I've used these functions before.  Trust me, you can read in overlapped mode using `ReadFile` (or `ReadFileEx`, which I prefer) and no `WaitCommEvent` at all.  `ReadFile` uses a kernel event in its OVERLAPPED parameter which you can wait on.  `WaitCommEvent` may tell you when there's activity on the serial port, but it will not give you the actual data.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I know al that. I developped USB-,Modem- ,SerialPort and Parallelport drivers and Applications for years ,in both legacy DOS code and Windows-APIs. Under Windows I never used anything else then Read- and WriteFile(-Ex) and an occassional DeviceIoControl.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need comm events to read data asynchronously.  Just call `ReadFile`, you'll get the "error" `ERROR_IO_PENDING`, and when data arrives the event will be signalled and you can then get the number of bytes `GetOverlappedResult`, the data will be in the buffer you originally supplied to `ReadFile`.